# how Can I create parent comment which contain children comments in schema mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The idea is about one comment contains children comments, it is about a comment contains responses. For that, I create my Comment schema like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
//to connect to our database 
import db from '../db/connectDB.js'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema // Define Schema method= mongoose;

    const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    id_parent : {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
         },
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        },
    content: {
        type: String,
        },
    created_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    counter_like: {
        type: Number,
        required:false,
      },
    status : {
        type: String,
         },
    });
    export default mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

then my parentComment schema like this:

```
   import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    //to connect to our database 
    import db from '../db/connectDB.js'
    
    const SchemaParent = mongoose.Schema // Define Schema method= mongoose;
    
        const ParentCommentSchema = new Schema({
            parent_comment:{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Comment'
            },    
            children_comments: [{
    
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'Comment'
                
            }]
           
        });
        export default mongoose.model('ParentComment', ParentCommentSchema);
```

It seems not clean, I don't want to insert the child comment every time I want to insert it directly in the the parent comment, I don't get the idea, any help

Comment: Is there a reason for those comment to exist in their own collection ? A comment will not exist if it's not attached to something isn't it ?

Comment: yes, I want them in the same collection, I try to dvp a comment and this comment can contains responses (so the idea is shema parent then add child comment to this parent)

Comment: So to develop the answers you're making another request to get a specific Comment's answers. This is why you're making a collection of comments instead of embedding directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply reference the parent ID in the comment itself

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    _id,
    parentId : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comments' },
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref 'Users'},
    [...]
});
```

This way you can `.find({parentId: commentId})` to find all the comments that would be "answers" of the `commentId` (parent). You will have an array of `Comment`

Otherwise you can embed directly the comments inside each others.

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    _id,
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref 'Users'}
});

commentSchema.add({comments: {type: [commentSchema], default: undefined})
```

You'd have something like :

```
comment {
    _id: 'qzrqrsrt',
    user: '1'
    content : "What do you guys think ?"
    comments : [
        {
            _id: 'qzrqzrqzr',
            user: '2',
            content: 'Ahah nice',
            comments: [
                {
                    _id: 'qiorqzpçrq',
                    user: '1',
                    content: 'Thanks'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: 'dryhsertse',
            user: '2'
            content: "I'll use it"
        }
    ]
}
```

But that would be a bit more difficult to find the comment you want to add answers to